# Dynamically adding Domain Names To Facebook App

Tags: php, facebook

I'm running to a problem where I have this application that runs under multiple cnames. For example:

```
app1.example.com
app2.example.com
```

Use the following cnames:

```
www.app1.com
www.app2.com
```

This causes Facebook Authentication to fail because the application domain name is incorrect, its not under example.com . So is there a way of using Facebook's API to dynamically add other names to the facebook app? I did not see this in the documentation so I am unsure.

BTW, I am using PHP to access the API on the server side, and JS for login.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/

Comment: @CBroe thanks, now if you put it as an answer, I can give u credit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#fields lists the `app_domains` property as *“Domains and subdomains this app can use (Editable via API)”*

And how to edit app properties is described further down the page – [#props](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#props)